# Statistics of signal with regularly spaced bursts of measurements

Tags: signal-processing, sensor-data

I want to investigate the statistical properties of the signal from a radar sensor, both simple quantities (e.g. mean, std dev, PSD) as well as investigating distributions between different measured quantities.

My question mostly relates to sampling frequency dependent metrics, like power spectral density.

If we say the sensor returns measurement packets at 10Hz where each packet can contain an unknown amount (e.g. 10-200) of individual measurements of a quantity, e.g. doppler speed, is it then meaningful to try and calculate the PSD with sampling frequency of 10Hz?